# How to get Android Studio to recognize file as source (test)

Tags: android, junit, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to create Robolectric tests for an android project (heck, i'd be happy to even make them unit tests)

I have the folder directory as:

```
MyApp
    - app
        - src
            - main
                - java
                    - com.myapp
                        HelloWorld
            - test
                - java
                    - com
                        - myapp
                            HelloWorldTest.java
```

The problem is that `HelloWorldTest.java` can't be run because it's not being recognized as source. how do i set it up so that i can run this class as a test?????

if i try to do `CMD + SHIFT + T` (shortcut for creating tests), it prompts to create the tests under the same directory as my source file and i do NOT want that

Answer (score 47):

In Android Studio 1.0 the scheme has changed a little bit.

Your path should be (app)/src/androidTest/java/com/myapp/HelloWorldTest.java

Here's how I set up Unit Tests in a new Android Studio project:

- Open app in Android Studio.
- Set the Project explorer (left hand window) to display 'Project' mode. Tap the little drop-down at the top left and select 'Project'.
- Right click the 'src' directory, 'New -> Directory'.
- Call new directory androidTest
- Right click androidTest and add a 'java' directory. It will appear in green (indicating it's a test src directory).
- Now right-click again and add a package, e.g. com.mycompany.myapp.tests
- Add a new class that extends AndroidTestCase.

Now add a new configuration for testing:

- Edit Configurations
- Click + at top left
- Select Android Tests
- In General Tab select your main module.
- Hit OK

Now you can run the tests.

Answer (score 32):

In Android Studio 1.3:

**Build > Select Build Variant**

In the Build Variants window, select **Unit Tests** as the Test Artifact.

Comment: The folder is "activated" as a valid source java folder once you selected the build variant.

Answer (score 10):

Follow the guidelines available here :

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing

and here

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Configuring-the-Structure

**Summary :**

As the first link says you have to rename your `test` directory as `instrumentTest` so Studio can automatically detects the sourceSets for your test project

**or**

Alternate is you can have your `tests` directory in root(with you main directory) and sources in a manner like `tests/java`, as the second link says

```
instrumenttest.setRoot("tests")
```

in sourceSets configuration under android tag

**From the document**

> Note: setRoot() moves the whole sourceSet (and its sub folders) to a
>   new folder. This moves src/instrumentTest/* to tests/* This is Android
>   specific and will not work on Java sourceSets.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I tried the first way, but i still keep getting `!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:` and `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!`. Most answers on stackoverflow tell me to just move JUnit upwards in the project module settings, but that doesn't solve the issue :/

Comment: Can you please include the screenshot of `File > Project Structure > yourmodule > Dependencies` in your question and also the build.gradle file  ?

Comment: This has changed for Android Studio 1.0 and up - the folder is now called androidTest. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem for a long time and finally I solved that.

To make Android Studio to recognize src/test dir as source you have to pick 'Unit Tests' in 'Build Variants'->'Test Artifact:'

However, in my project I hadn't had 'Unit Tests' I only had 'Android Instrumentation tests'. This is two different types of unit-tests in Android.

See: http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/index.html 

1. Unit Tests - Local Unit Tests

2. Android Instrumentation tests - Instrumented Unit Tests

That is not obvious at all but inside 'Build Variants'->'Test Artifact:' you does not have 'Unit Tests' option when you have multiple modules in your project.

My project dir looked like this:

:project

-:module1

-:module2

-:module3

-:module4

-:module5

-settings.gradle -> include ':module1',':module2', ...

These modules are not really linked to each other, but it is how it has to be for many other developers who came from Eclipse. That was a problem.

Then I created separate project for my module only:

:project

-:module1

-settings.gradle -> include ':module1'

After that 'Unit Tests' appeared in 'Build Variants'->'Test Artifact:' and  I can choose between Local Unit Tests and Android Instrumentation tests now.