# folder under androidTest is not green

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit

Related to this question: [How to get Android Studio to recognize file as source (test)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927447/how-to-get-android-studio-to-recognize-file-as-source-test)

I am running Android Studio 1.2.1.1.

If I am trying to create a test, I right click on the class name and select Go To -> Test -> Create New Test

I am then given a dialogue which asks me where I would like to put my test.  I select a place. (I put it under src/androidTest)

In order for Android Studio to recognize this test, the java folder under androidTest needs to be green?  How do I make it green?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Build Variants UI Element,

[image]

go to the "Test Artifact" drop down box, 
and select "Android Instrumentation Tests"

[image: instrumentation tests dropdown]

see if it turned green.