# Android Studio add test folder or module to existing project

Tags: android, junit

I want to add testing to my android app in Android Studio 1.4. When I try to create and add them to `/test` folder under a root folder they aren't executed. Also, I tried to create a separate module for tests but there are no Test Module in a wizard. How can I add and run Junit tests?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28630023/4955008 
This helped me a lot, Studio recognized folder as a test and it passed.

Comment: I agree. I had to write tests for a project in which no test folders were present. I followed the answer (pointed by above link) and it was not that difficult